# Why i can not access image while using azure blob as storage provider in virtocommerce?

Tags: azure, e-commerce, azure-blob-storage, virtocommerce

I'm using azure blob as storage provider, after i save images for products, i can not see the images in front-end, the image url is correct, but it returns error:

> The specified resource does not exist

I think this is something related to azure blob permission. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be due to blob storage container in azure not configured as public, so browser accessing the image can't download it due to security. Change container to public and it should start working.

Admin authenticates with azure blob storage and that is the reason why you can see images in admin.